# Mysql2::Error: Table doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `sessions`

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I just cloned an application from my developer and I want to set it up on my computer.  I get this error when I go to `localhost:3000`, and I don't really understand what it means.

Error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - Mysql2::Error: Table 
'goacquire_development.sessions' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `sessions`:
```

I think it could be my installation process, I'll appreciate if someone could explain this error to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few ideas:

1. Make sure MySQL is running on your local machine.
2. Make sure you have run `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate`.
3. Make sure you have a `database.yml` file configured with MySQL settings.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

- Install MySQL server on your machine
- Config database.yml (Create new if your app don't have.)
- Run commands:

> ```
> # cd /path/to/your/app
> # bundle install
> # rake db:create
> # rake db:migrate
> # rails s
> ```